# SharedPreferences is being reset every time the app started

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

**I have this code on my MainActivity.java:**

```
  SharedPreferences ids = getSharedPreferences(AddedIds, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPrefernces.Editor editor = ids.edit();
    if (ids.getStringSet(AddedIds, id).isEmpty()) {
        Set<String> id = new HashSet<String>();
        editor.putStringSet(AddedIds, id);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

This code is checking whether the `Set<String>` is existing in the `SharedPreferences`. If not, then it adds the `Set<String>` to the `SharedPreferences`.

The problem is that the code is being activated whenever I open the app, althrough it exist in the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: What is "AddedIds"? I always read preferences through the activity (I am only using one) getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); and it works.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences.contains` before adding value

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of a snippet

Comment: AddedIds is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe id is the string that you are searching in stringset. Change your code to below.

```
Set<String> set = ids.getStringSet(AddedIds, null);
    Boolean keyfound = false;
    if ( set != null){
        for (String key : set){
            if(key.equals(id)){
                keyfound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!keyfound){
            set.add(id);
            editor.putStringSet(AddedIds, set);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
    else{
        set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add(id);
        editor.putStringSet(AddedIds, set);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is it checks if the set stored in `SharedPreferences` is empty.

What you want is to use [contains method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String)) that checks if a field exists. So that should be

```
SharedPreferences ids = getSharedPreferences(AddedIds, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPrefernces.Editor editor = ids.edit();
if (!ids.contains(AddedIds)) {
    Set<String> id = new HashSet<String>();
    editor.putStringSet(AddedIds, id);
    editor.apply();
}
```